# reestablish WAMP subscriptions after reconnect

Tags: wamp, crossbar, autobahnjs

I'm using autobahn-js (0.11.2) in a web browser and the crossbar message router (v17.2.1) in the backend.

In case of a network disconnect (e.g. due to poor network) the autobahn-js client can be configured to try to reconnect periodically.

Now in my web app powered by autobahn subscriptions to different WAMP topics are created `session.subscribe('my.topic', myhandleevent)` dynamically.

Is there a best practice on how to reregister all active subscriptions upon reconnect? Is that maybe configurable even?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think resubscriptions are not configurable out-of-box. But *onopen* is fired after reconnect, so placing subscriptions initialization inside it, will do the thing:

```
var ses;
var onOpenFunctions = [];

function addOnOpenFunction(name) {
    onOpenFunctions.push(name);
    if (ses !== null) {
        window[name]();
    }
}

connection.onopen = function (session, details) {
    ses = session;
    for (var i = 0; i < onOpenFunctions.length; i++) {
        window[onOpenFunctions[i]]();
    }
};
```

Then if you want subscribe dynamically you have to do this:

```
function subscribeTopic() {
    session.subscribe('my.topic', myhandleevent)
}
addOnOpenFunction('subscribeTopic');
```

Comment: thanks. This almost does it. I would always put the subscribe functions in the onOpenFunctions array because they need to be reexecuted on every network drop and reconnect. So I would remove the `if` in the ´addOnOpenFunction` and always go with it's first block.

Comment: I updated code in *addOnOpenFunction()*. Please accept answer if it is correct now.

Comment: come to think about it, this should be included in autobahn-js as an option in the subscribe function. I'll file a feature request.